# Background transparent color

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to make transparent color in my slide out menu like youtube,any ideas?
Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add easily blur effect using **iOS 8** default `UIVisualEffect` and `UIVisualEffectView` Make Sure it will only available above iOS 8.

```
UIVisualEffect *blurV = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *visualV = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurV];

visualV.frame = yourImageView.bounds;
[yourImageView addSubview:visualEffectView];
```

You can add one of three default effects

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIBlurEffectStyle) {
UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight,
UIBlurEffectStyleLight,
UIBlurEffectStyleDark
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

For Swift

```
var visualV = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)) as UIVisualEffectView
visualV.frame = yourImageView.bounds
yourImageView.addSubview(visualV)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,sir.Can you please write some example in swift?Coz i am newbie to swift.To me your syantax looks like objc or strange.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But,i still don't know where to put your code.In my viewDidLoad(),i put "self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "LeftMenu_2.jpg")!)" that image for now.

Comment: @Thiha6245 Take one UIImageView and add it in xib. outlet it. and then add below code in viewDidAppear. you can also add `UIVisualEffectView` directly using. `self.view.addSubview(visualV)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell?
{
    println("The indexPath code is \(indexPath!.row)")

    let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FlowerTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FlowerTableViewCell

    let flower = flowers[indexPath!.row] as Flower

    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: flower.backgroundImage))

    cell.backgroundView = backgroundImageView

    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView

    visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.bounds.width, cell.bounds.height)
    backgroundImageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)

    cell.textLabel.text = flower.name
    cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps you. You may also take a look on this blog-article:
http://blog.bubbly.net/2013/09/11/slick-tricks-for-ios-blur-effect/